# ASPX AJAX is loading full page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to update a label field in ASPX page using AJAX. 
When I try following code the whole page seems to refresh and there seems to be jerky effect. Is there a way that label fields gets updated seamlessly ? There are other title and text on the page.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:Timer runat="server" id="UpdateTimer" interval="1000" ontick="UpdateTimer_Tick" />  
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="TimedPanel" updatemode="Always">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblCurrentStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Any alternate I should be using ?

Comment: what is your trigger for update panel?

Comment: Updatemode is set to Always. As soon as page load, it starts reloading every sec. as interval is set to 1000ms